# Restricting single dot in textbox

Tags: regex, validation, gwt, textbox

I am working validation in gwt. I am having textbox which allows only whole numbers and decimalvalues. I used regex pattern like `^[0-9.]+$`.It works fine. But when i entered single dot like `.` it accepts. How can i restrict single dot on above regex pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$
```

So a series of digits, optionally followed by a period and a series of digits.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

It will match integers or decimal numbers.

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

For our GWT project we are using Hibernate validator and annotations like

```
@DecimalMax(value = "9999999.99")
@DecimalMin(value = "0.01")
private BigDecimal amount;
```

instead of regular expressions.